# Ruby on Rails 7.0.1 and Tailwind 3, tailwind classes are not being displayed in the browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm trying to set up my rails project with tailwind, but none of the actual tailwind changes are showing up in the browser. In devtools the class is displayed, but it doesn't make any change in the browser (the background is not red). RoR version is 7.0.1, Tailwindcss is 3.0.13, and Ruby is 2.7.2. I set it up following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JsNtLiph87Y and here is my tailwind.config:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './app/views/**/*.html.erb',
    './app/helpers/**/*.rb',
    './app/javascript/**/*.js'
  ],
  mode: 'jit',
}
```

here is my Gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby "2.7.2"

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem "rails", github: "rails/rails", branch: "main"
gem "rails", "~> 7.0.1"

# The original asset pipeline for Rails [https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails]
gem "sprockets-rails"

# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem "pg", "~> 1.1"

# Use the Puma web server [https://github.com/puma/puma]
gem "puma", "~> 5.0"

# Bundle and transpile JavaScript [https://github.com/rails/jsbundling-rails]
gem "jsbundling-rails"

# Hotwire's SPA-like page accelerator [https://turbo.hotwired.dev]
gem "turbo-rails"

# Hotwire's modest JavaScript framework [https://stimulus.hotwired.dev]
gem "stimulus-rails"

# Bundle and process CSS [https://github.com/rails/cssbundling-rails]
gem "cssbundling-rails"

# Build JSON APIs with ease [https://github.com/rails/jbuilder]
gem "jbuilder"

# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
gem "redis", "~> 4.0"

# Use Kredis to get higher-level data types in Redis [https://github.com/rails/kredis]
# gem "kredis"

# Use Active Model has_secure_password [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html#securepassword]
# gem "bcrypt", "~> 3.1.7"

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby ]

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem "bootsnap", require: false

# Use Sass to process CSS
# gem "sassc-rails"

# Use Active Storage variants [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#transforming-images]
# gem "image_processing", "~> 1.2"

group :development, :test do
  # See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-debug-gem
  gem "debug", platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ]
end

group :development do
  # Use console on exceptions pages [https://github.com/rails/web-console]
  gem "web-console"

  # Add speed badges [https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler]
  # gem "rack-mini-profiler"

  # Speed up commands on slow machines / big apps [https://github.com/rails/spring]
  # gem "spring"
end

group :test do
  # Use system testing [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#system-testing]
  gem "capybara"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
  gem "webdrivers"
end
```

here is my application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Nekonomicon</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload", defer: true %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here is the Home index page (route is home#index) index.html.erb

```
<div class="bg-red-500">HELP</div>
```

The HELP is displaying but not the background

Comment: What version of Node are you running?

Answer (score 20):

Running `rake tailwindcss:build` may solve the problem, but you would not want to do that after every change of a HTML class.

What you should do instead is starting your development webserver with `bin/dev` (instead of `rails server`) which will use Foreman to not only start Puma but also make Tailwind listen for changes in your CSS and (re)build the CSS file on the fly.

Comment: Running the rake command after installing the gems worked for me.

Comment: @CJG did this require you to do it after every change for it to be reflected in the browser?

Answer (score 4):

You have to rebuild your css by command:

```
rails tailwindcss:build
```

Or try to use `hotwire-livereload` [gem](https://kirillplatonov.com/posts/hotwire-livereload/) for live reloading

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30935520)

Comment: add option for live reloading that could fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

in development you can use

```
rails tailwindcss:watch
```

https://github.com/rails/tailwindcss-rails#update-assets-automatically

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the only thing that I needed to do was run:

`rails tailwindcss:build`

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add stylesheet tag to application layout if you install Tailwind manually

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "tailwind", "inter-font", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

During your application's development, running Tailwind in "watch" mode is beneficial. This ensures that any changes are automatically reflected in the generated CSS output. This can be achieved by using the [Puma](https://puma.io/) plugin provided by this gem to integrate the "watch" feature with the `rails server`. To do this, add the following line to your `puma.rb` configuration:

```
plugin :tailwindcss if ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV", "development") == "development"`
```

Afterwards, running `rails server` will initiate the Tailwind watch process in the background.

Reference: [Tailwind CSS for Rails](https://github.com/rails/tailwindcss-rails?tab=readme-ov-file#live-rebuild)